# Please Recommend a Simple Automated GUI recording application?

Tags: user-interface, automation

I need to have an application simply record mouse gestures and keyboard strokes that will then be able to play this recording back.  I will run this on a few computers on the network to simulate multi-users.

The app does not need to create any output scripts or code I just want to run the recording over and over again.

I'm not sure if its possible but I'd like to be able to run the recording numerous times on the same machine with a startup time delay. This is not essential and I'm not even sure if its possible.

I have seen Ranorex and also an app called AutoMe. Not sure if they are any good so can you please recommend any apps that fulfil my requirements.

Thanks

**UPDATE: Anyone?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Autohotkey (http://www.autohotkey.com/) is pretty nice. It has a macro recorder that is fairly simple and easy to use, and if you want to create more powerful scripts, you can do just about anything with it. There is a fairly low learning curve, and good online documentation and community.

Answer (score 0):

The two you mentioned are fine. Try, also, "TinyTask" under "Free Software Tools!" on [**this web page**](http://www.vtaskstudio.com/support.php).  If that doesn't cut it, then, seriously, buying the full *vTask Studio* product on that website could quite probably be the best seventy bucks you ever spent. I kid you not; it puts AutoMe to shame! It's truly amazing; and it'll accommodate complex and conditional pauses, and can even recognize when something needed isn't on the screen... and a whole raft of cool stuff like that.

The free "TinyTask" thingy is no slouch, though. Definitely try that first. It may work just fine for you.

There's also "Sikuli Script."  And "AutoIt" is nice.  It seems like there's one other I should be remembering, but it's not coming to me at the moment. If I remember it, I'll return and add it.

Hope that helps!